# How to implement one authentication server for many apps?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, authentication

How can I implement one server for authentication and have many apps use that?
For example : one user implemented in app "A" can also use app "B" too..
My API is .Net Core and database is MongoDB.

Comment: You can read about using openidconnect to implement SSO feature for all your apps.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the apps are end client consumers (frontends) or micro service apps where each one uses the same authentication provider?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya is there a way to have it on .Net core api??

Comment: @tony my apps are client ends like react... actually i want a central authentication server for my different apps

Answer (score 0):

Check this article here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

OAUTH is the way to go if you want a centralized authentication mechanism that gives access to multiple resources

Answer (score 0):

Maybe micro-service architecture is useful here.

You can implement 3 APIs, one is only for authentication, one for app1, and one for app2.

Then in app1 and app2 call authentication method from first API.

Also keep in mind you have to implement users table for both apps to store users actions and data.

(Also you can use ready to use authentication services too)

Comment: tnx but i did not get " implement user table for both apps"

Comment: for example the user in app2 have an score you want to store for him in app2 database, so there must be a user table which you can reference the score to it.